Trying to get Datadog dashboard set up but cannot get avg times for endpoint
I am trying to build out a dashboard in Datadog that just shows the average times for various endpoint for all calls that have an http status of 200.
I cannot seem to get this syntax correct.
Let's say the endpoint is /site/cart, and I can see the calls in the logs when searching using that endpoint so they are getting tracked. They have the duration on them.
What kind of widget do I need in order to show the average duration of all the calls to that endpoint that have an http status of 200?  What does that query look like?
